# Is this an idiomatic worker thread pool in Go?

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm attempting to write a simple worker pool with goroutines.

- Is the code I wrote idiomatic?  If not, then what should change?
- I want to be able to set the maximum number of worker threads to 5 and block until a worker becomes available if all 5 are busy.  How would I extend this to only have a pool of 5 workers max?  Do I spawn the static 5 goroutines, and give each the `work_channel`?

code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func worker(id string, work string, o chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    sleepMs := rand.Intn(1000)
    fmt.Printf("worker '%s' received: '%s', sleep %dms\n", id, work, sleepMs)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(sleepMs) * time.Millisecond)
    o <- work + fmt.Sprintf("-%dms", sleepMs)
}

func main() {
    var work_channel = make(chan string)
    var results_channel = make(chan string)

    // create goroutine per item in work_channel
    go func() {
        var c = 0
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        for work := range work_channel {
            wg.Add(1)
            go worker(fmt.Sprintf("%d", c), work, results_channel, &wg)
            c++
        }
        wg.Wait()
        fmt.Println("closing results channel")
        close(results_channel)
    }()

    // add work to the work_channel
    go func() {
        for c := 'a'; c < 'z'; c++ {
            work_channel <- fmt.Sprintf("%c", c)
        }
        close(work_channel)
        fmt.Println("sent work to work_channel")
    }()

    for x := range results_channel {
        fmt.Printf("result: %s\n", x)
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer here which shows how to create a goroutine worker pool at the end (as an alternative solution): [Bruteforce MD5 Password cracker](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114376/bruteforce-md5-password-cracker)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your solution is not a worker goroutine pool in any sense: your code does not limit concurrent goroutines, and it does not "reuse" goroutines (it always starts a new one when a new job is received).

### Producer-consumer pattern

As posted at [Bruteforce MD5 Password cracker](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114376/bruteforce-md5-password-cracker), you can make use of the [producer-consumer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). You could have a designated *producer* goroutine that would generate the jobs (things to do / calculate), and send them on a *jobs* channel. You could have a fixed pool of *consumer* goroutines (e.g. 5 of them) which would loop over the channel on which jobs are delivered, and each would execute / complete the received jobs.

The *producer* goroutine could simply close the `jobs` channel when all jobs were generated and sent, properly signalling *consumers* that no more jobs will be coming. The `for ... range` construct on a channel handles the "close" event and terminates properly. Note that all jobs sent before closing the channel will still be delivered.

This would result in a clean design, would result in fixed (but arbitrary) number of goroutines, and it would always utilize 100% CPU (if # of goroutines is greater than # of CPU cores). It also has the advantage that it can be "throttled" with the proper selection of the channel capacity (buffered channel) and the number of *consumer* goroutines.

<sup>Note that this model to have a designated producer goroutine is not mandatory. You could have multiple goroutines to produce jobs too, but then you must synchronize them too to only close the `jobs` channel when all producer goroutines are done producing jobs - else attempting to send another job on the `jobs` channel when it has already been closed results in a runtime panic. Usually producing jobs are cheap and can be produced at a much quicker rate than they can be executed, so this model to produce them in 1 goroutine while many are consuming / executing them is good in practice.</sup>

**Handling results:**

If jobs have results, you may choose to have a designated *result* channel on which results could be delivered ("sent back"), or you may choose to handle the results in the consumer when the job is completed / finished. This latter may even be implemented by having a "callback" function that handles the results. The important thing is whether results can be processed independently or they need to be merged (e.g. map-reduce framework) or aggregated.

If you go with a `results` channel, you also need a goroutine that receives values from it, preventing consumers to get blocked (would occur if buffer of `results` would get filled).

### With `results` channel

Instead of sending simple `string` values as jobs and results, I would create a wrapper type which can hold any additional info and so it is much more flexible:

```
type Job struct {
    Id     int
    Work   string
    Result string
}
```

Note that the `Job` struct also wraps the result, so when we send back the result, it also contains the original `Job` as the context - *often very useful*. Also note that it is profitable to just send pointers (`*Job`) on the channels instead of `Job` values so no need to make "countless" copies of `Job`s, and also the size of the `Job` struct value becomes irrelevant.

**Here is how this producer-consumer could look like:**

I would use 2 [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) values, their role will follow:

```
var wg, wg2 sync.WaitGroup
```

The producer is responsible to generate jobs to be executed:

```
func produce(jobs chan<- *Job) {
    // Generate jobs:
    id := 0
    for c := 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++ {
        id++
        jobs <- &Job{Id: id, Work: fmt.Sprintf("%c", c)}
    }
    close(jobs)
}
```

When done (no more jobs), the `jobs` channel is closed which signals consumers that no more jobs will arrive.

Note that `produce()` sees the `jobs` channel as *send only*, because that's what the producer needs to do only with that: *send* jobs on it (besides *closing* it, but that is also permitted on a *send only* channel). An accidental receive in the producer would be a compile time error (detected early, at compile time).

The consumer's responsibility is to receive jobs as long as jobs can be received, and execute them:

```
func consume(id int, jobs <-chan *Job, results chan<- *Job) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for job := range jobs {
        sleepMs := rand.Intn(1000)
        fmt.Printf("worker #%d received: '%s', sleep %dms\n", id, job.Work, sleepMs)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(sleepMs) * time.Millisecond)
        job.Result = job.Work + fmt.Sprintf("-%dms", sleepMs)
        results <- job
    }
}
```

Note that `consume()` sees the `jobs` channel as *receive only*; consumer only needs to *receive* from it. Similarly the `results` channel is *send only* for the consumer.

Also note that the `results` channel **cannot** be closed here as there are multiple consumer goroutines, and only the first attempting to close it would succeed and further ones would result in runtime panic! `results` channel can (must) be closed after all consumer goroutines ended, because then we can be sure no further values (results) will be sent on the `results` channel.

We have results which need to be analyzed:

```
func analyze(results <-chan *Job) {
    defer wg2.Done()
    for job := range results {
        fmt.Printf("result: %s\n", job.Result)
    }
}
```

As you can see, this also receives results as long as they may come (until `results` channel is closed). The `results` channel for the analyzer is *receive only*.

Please note the use of channel types: whenever it is sufficient, use only a *unidirectional* channel type to detect and prevent errors early, at compile time. Only use *bidirectional* channel type if you do need both directions.

And this is how all these are glued together:

```
func main() {
    jobs := make(chan *Job, 100)    // Buffered channel
    results := make(chan *Job, 100) // Buffered channel

    // Start consumers:
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ { // 5 consumers
        wg.Add(1)
        go consume(i, jobs, results)
    }
    // Start producing
    go produce(jobs)

    // Start analyzing:
    wg2.Add(1)
    go analyze(results)

    wg.Wait() // Wait all consumers to finish processing jobs

    // All jobs are processed, no more values will be sent on results:
    close(results)

    wg2.Wait() // Wait analyzer to analyze all results
}
```

**Example output:**

Here is an example output:

As you can see, results are coming and getting analyzed before all the jobs would be enqueued:

```
worker #4 received: 'e', sleep 81ms
worker #0 received: 'a', sleep 887ms
worker #1 received: 'b', sleep 847ms
worker #2 received: 'c', sleep 59ms
worker #3 received: 'd', sleep 81ms
worker #2 received: 'f', sleep 318ms
result: c-59ms
worker #4 received: 'g', sleep 425ms
result: e-81ms
worker #3 received: 'h', sleep 540ms
result: d-81ms
worker #2 received: 'i', sleep 456ms
result: f-318ms
worker #4 received: 'j', sleep 300ms
result: g-425ms
worker #3 received: 'k', sleep 694ms
result: h-540ms
worker #4 received: 'l', sleep 511ms
result: j-300ms
worker #2 received: 'm', sleep 162ms
result: i-456ms
worker #1 received: 'n', sleep 89ms
result: b-847ms
worker #0 received: 'o', sleep 728ms
result: a-887ms
worker #1 received: 'p', sleep 274ms
result: n-89ms
worker #2 received: 'q', sleep 211ms
result: m-162ms
worker #2 received: 'r', sleep 445ms
result: q-211ms
worker #1 received: 's', sleep 237ms
result: p-274ms
worker #3 received: 't', sleep 106ms
result: k-694ms
worker #4 received: 'u', sleep 495ms
result: l-511ms
worker #3 received: 'v', sleep 466ms
result: t-106ms
worker #1 received: 'w', sleep 528ms
result: s-237ms
worker #0 received: 'x', sleep 258ms
result: o-728ms
worker #2 received: 'y', sleep 47ms
result: r-445ms
worker #2 received: 'z', sleep 947ms
result: y-47ms
result: u-495ms
result: x-258ms
result: v-466ms
result: w-528ms
result: z-947ms
```

Try the complete application on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2rIkRiwcjs9).

### Without a `results` channel

Code simplifies significantly if we don't use a `results` channel but the consumer goroutines handle the result right away (print it in our case). In this case we don't need 2 `sync.WaitGroup` values (the 2nd was only needed to wait for the analyzer to complete).

Without a `results` channel the complete solution is like this:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

type Job struct {
    Id   int
    Work string
}

func produce(jobs chan<- *Job) {
    // Generate jobs:
    id := 0
    for c := 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++ {
        id++
        jobs <- &Job{Id: id, Work: fmt.Sprintf("%c", c)}
    }
    close(jobs)
}

func consume(id int, jobs <-chan *Job) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for job := range jobs {
        sleepMs := rand.Intn(1000)
        fmt.Printf("worker #%d received: '%s', sleep %dms\n", id, job.Work, sleepMs)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(sleepMs) * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Printf("result: %s\n", job.Work+fmt.Sprintf("-%dms", sleepMs))
    }
}

func main() {
    jobs := make(chan *Job, 100) // Buffered channel

    // Start consumers:
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ { // 5 consumers
        wg.Add(1)
        go consume(i, jobs)
    }
    // Start producing
    go produce(jobs)

    wg.Wait() // Wait all consumers to finish processing jobs
}
```

Output is "like" that of with `results` channel (but of course execution/completion order is random).

Try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OSJY28JpAlm).

Comment: I like this answer. Why remove and create new goroutines when they're all  doing the same thing? Even though goroutines are light and cheap, we shouldn't take that for granted. I believe this is good practice.

Comment: Whoa, amazing!  Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could double/tripe/quadruple like this!

Comment: Firstly thanks, this is awesome. I think you may have one extra `wg.Done()` then `wg.Add(1)` since you `wg.Add(1)` for each consumer and defer a `wg.Done()` for each consumer, but you also `wg.Done()` for produce. Which means that the `wg.Wait()` might not wait till all 5 consumers are done. Just checking?

Comment: @AmaJayJB You're right, nice catch. Thanks. I fixed it by removing the `wg.Done()` from the producer.

Comment: Wouldn’t the actual Go terminology call this a fan out pipeline?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Fan out is used when multiple channels are merged into a single one. This is not used in the answer.

Comment: Wouldn’t that be a fan in?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg You're right, fan out is when multiple functions read from a channel until it is closed. Although that is also not used in the answer, there is only one consumer.

Comment: Amazing answer! enterprise service would also need `context` to cancel or timeout the workflow

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a counting semaphore to limit goroutine concurrency.

```
var tokens = make(chan struct{}, 20)

func worker(id string, work string, o chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    tokens <- struct{}{} // acquire a token before performing work
    sleepMs := rand.Intn(1000)
    fmt.Printf("worker '%s' received: '%s', sleep %dms\n", id, work, sleepMs)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(sleepMs) * time.Millisecond)
    <-tokens // release the token
    o <- work + fmt.Sprintf("-%dms", sleepMs)
}
```

This is the general design used to limit the number of workers. You can of course change location of releasing/acquiring of tokens to fit your code.

Comment: You should be careful when mentioning parallelism. `go func(){}()` does not always guarantee parallelism. With that aside, I think this is the simplest way to limit the number of goroutines in flight.

Comment: it's rarely useful to create lots of goroutines and them have them wait on a counting semaphore starting at 20.  instead create 20 goroutines and have them get work from a channel