# Simple worker pool in Go

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I am trying to implement a simple worker pool in go and keep running into issues. All I want to do is have a set number of workers that do a set amount of work before getting more work to do. The code I am using looks similar to:

```
    jobs := make(chan imageMessage, 1)
    results := make(chan imageMessage, 1)

    for w := 0; w < 2; w++ {
        go worker(jobs, results)
    }

    for j := 0; j < len(images); j++ {
        jobs <- imageMessage{path: paths[j], img: images[j]}
    }
    close(jobs)

    for r := 0; r < len(images); r++ {
        <-results
    }
}

func worker(jobs <-chan imageMessage, results chan<- imageMessage) {
    for j := range jobs {
        processImage(j.path, j.img)
        results <- j
    }
}
```

My understanding is that this should create 2 workers that can do 1 "thing" at a time and will continue to get more work as they complete that 1 thing until there is nothing else to do. However, I get `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

If I set the buffer to something huge like 100, this works, but I want to be able to limit the work done at a time.

I feel like I'm close, but obviously missing something.

Comment: Related: [Is this an idiomatic worker thread pool in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170852/is-this-an-idiomatic-worker-thread-pool-in-go)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you only start "draining" the `results` channel, once you successfully sent all jobs on the `jobs` channel. But for you to be able to send all jobs, either the `jobs` channel must have big enough buffer, or worker goroutines must be able to consume jobs from it.

But a worker goroutines when consuming a job, before it could take the next one, sends the result on the `results` channel. If the buffer of the `results` channel is full, sending the result will block.

But the last part – a worker goroutine blocked in sending the result – can only be "unblocked" by receiving from the `results` channel – which you don't until you can send all the jobs. Deadlock if the buffer of the `jobs` channel and the `results` channel cannot hold all your jobs. This also explains why it works if you increase the buffer size to a big value: if the jobs can fit into the buffers, deadlock will not occur, and after all jobs are sent successfully, your final loop will drain the `results` channel.

The solution? Run generating-and-sending jobs in its own goroutine, so you can start receiving from the `results` channel "immediately" without having to wait to send all jobs, which means the worker goroutines will not get blocked forever trying to send results:

```
go func() {
    for j := 0; j < len(images); j++ {
        jobs <- imageMessage{path: paths[j], img: images[j]}
    }
    close(jobs)
}()
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jvitOGmzpl).

Also check out a similar implementation in [Is this an idiomatic worker thread pool in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170852/is-this-an-idiomatic-worker-thread-pool-in-go/38172204#38172204)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this worker. Simple and efficient. https://github.com/tamnguyenvt/go-worker

```
NewWorkerManager(WorkerManagerParams{
    WorkerSize: <number of workers>,
    RelaxAfter: <sleep for awhile to relax server after given duration>,
    RelaxDuration: <relax duration>,
    WorkerFunc: <your worker function here>,
    LogEnable: <enable log or not>,
    StopTimeout: <timeout all workers after given duration>,
}
```