# Process concurrent HTTP requests in Golang

Tags: http, go, concurrency

I'm trying to process a file which contains 200 URLs and use each URL to make an HTTP request. I need to process 10 URLs concurrently maximum each time (code should block until 10 URLs finish processing). Tried to solve it in go but I keep getting the whole file processed with 200 concurrent connection created.

```
for scanner.Scan() { // loop through each url in the file
        // send each url to golang HTTPrequest
        go HTTPrequest(scanner.Text(), channel, &wg)
}
fmt.Println(<-channel)
wg.Wait()
```

What should i do?

Comment: What would make it limit it to 10 goroutines? The number 10 is nowhere to be seen in your code. Check out this related question: [Is this an idiomatic worker thread pool in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170852/is-this-an-idiomatic-worker-thread-pool-in-go/38172204#38172204)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pool of 10 go routines reading from a [`channel`](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) should fulfill your requirements.

```
work := make(chan string)

// get original 200 urls
var urlsToProcess []string = seedUrls() 

// startup pool of 10 go routines and read urls from work channel 
for i := 0; i<=10; i++ {
  go func(w chan string) {
     url := <-w
  }(work)
}

// write urls to the work channel, blocking until a worker goroutine
// is able to start work
for _, url := range urlsToProcess {
  work <- url
}
```

Cleanup and request results are left as an exercise for you.  Go channels is will block until one of the worker routines is able to read.

Comment: Sorry to revisit the question, but what if you have bounded parallelism scenario, in which you need to read the URLs from a file and you do want to loop through the file line by line.

Answer (score 2):

code like this

```
longTimeAct := func(index int, w chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        println(index)
        <-w
}
wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
ws := make(chan struct{}, 10)
for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        ws <- struct{}{}
        wg.Add(1)
        go longTimeAct(i, ws, wg)
}
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.