# How to send of GO routines in a worker pool

Tags: go

im writing an algorithm to break down an image into segments and manipulate it, however the way im currently using Go routines isn't quite optimal.

I'd like to split it into a worker pool, firing off routines and having each worker take a new job until the image is completed.

I have it split into 8 as such:

```
var bounds = img.Bounds()
            var halfHeight = bounds.Max.Y / 2
            var eighthOne = halfHeight / 4
            var eighthTwo = eighthOne + eighthOne
            var eighthThree = eighthOne + eighthTwo
            var eighthFive = halfHeight + eighthOne
            var eighthSix = halfHeight + eighthTwo
            var eighthSeven = halfHeight + eighthThree

            elapsed := time.Now()
            go Threshold(pic, c2, 0, eighthOne)
            go Threshold(pic, c5, eighthOne, eighthTwo)
            go Threshold(pic, c6, eighthTwo, eighthThree)
            go Threshold(pic, c7, eighthThree, halfHeight)
            go Threshold(pic, c8, halfHeight, eighthFive)
            go Threshold(pic, c9, eighthFive, eighthSix)
            go Threshold(pic, c10, eighthSix, eighthSeven)
            go Threshold(pic, c11, eighthSeven, bounds.Max.Y)
```

From which i then fire off Go routines one after another, how can i optimise this into a worker system?

Thanks

Comment: See [Is this an idiomatic worker thread pool in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170852/is-this-an-idiomatic-worker-thread-pool-in-go/38172204#38172204)

Comment: The answer is most certainly buffered channels. If you haven't gone through it, the go tour explains go concurrency primitives quite well. https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a generic pattern for implementing concurrent image processors giving control to the caller over the image partitioning to split the work in n parts and over the concurrency level of the execution (i.e. the number of worker goroutines used for executing the (possibly different) number of processing jobs).

See the `pprocess` func which implements the whole pattern taking a `Partitioner` and a `Processor`, the former being a func that takes the job of returning n image partitions to operate on, and the latter being a func which will be used for processing each partition.

I implemented the vertical splitting you expressed in your code example in the func `splitVert` which returns a function which can split an image in n vertical sections.

For doing some actual work I implemented the `gray` func which is a `Processor` that transform pixel colors to gray levels (luminance).

Here's the working code:

```
type MutableImage interface {
    image.Image
    Set(x, y int, c color.Color)
}

type Processor func(MutableImage, image.Rectangle)

type Partitioner func(image.Image) []image.Rectangle

func pprocess(i image.Image, concurrency int, part Partitioner, proc Processor) image.Image {
    m := image.NewRGBA(i.Bounds())
    draw.Draw(m, i.Bounds(), i, i.Bounds().Min, draw.Src)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    c := make(chan image.Rectangle, concurrency*2)
    for n := 0; n < concurrency; n++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            for r := range c {
                proc(m, r)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    for _, p := range part(i) {
        c <- p
    }
    close(c)
    wg.Wait()
    return m
}

func gray(i MutableImage, r image.Rectangle) {
    for x := r.Min.X; x <= r.Max.X; x++ {
        for y := r.Min.Y; y <= r.Max.Y; y++ {
            c := i.At(x, y)
            r, g, b, _ := c.RGBA()
            l := 0.299*float64(r) + 0.587*float64(g) + 0.114*float64(b)
            i.Set(x, y, color.Gray{uint8(l / 256)})
        }
    }
}

func splitVert(c int) Partitioner {
    return func(i image.Image) []image.Rectangle {
        b := i.Bounds()
        s := float64(b.Dy()) / float64(c)
        rs := make([]image.Rectangle, c)
        for n := 0; n < c; n++ {
            m := float64(n)
            x0 := b.Min.X
            y0 := b.Min.Y + int(0.5+m*s)
            x1 := b.Max.X
            y1 := b.Min.Y + int(0.5+(m+1)*s)
            if n < c-1 {
                y1--
            }
            rs[n] = image.Rect(x0, y0, x1, y1)
        }
        return rs
    }
}

func main() {
    i, err := jpeg.Decode(os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("decoding image: %v", err)
    }
    o := pprocess(i, runtime.NumCPU(), splitVert(8), gray)
    err = jpeg.Encode(os.Stdout, o, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("encoding image: %v", err)
    }
}
```