# Concurrent filesystem scanning

Tags: go, file-io, concurrency, parallel-processing, filesystems

I want to obtain file information (file name & size in bytes) for the files in a directory.  But there are a lot of sub-directory (~ 1000) and files (~40 000).

Actually my solution is to use [filepath.Walk()](https://golang.org/src/path/filepath/path.go?s=9626:9671#L331) to obtain file information for each file. But this is quite long.

```
func visit(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if f.Mode().IsRegular() {
        fmt.Printf("Visited: %s File name: %s Size: %d bytes\n", path, f.Name(), f.Size())
    }
    return nil
}
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    root := "C:/Users/HERNOUX-06523/go/src/boilerpipe" //flag.Arg(0)
    filepath.Walk(root, visit)
}
```

Is it possible to do parallel/concurrent processing using [filepath.Walk()](https://golang.org/src/path/filepath/path.go?s=9626:9671#L331)?

Comment: Creating a goroutine for each file will not help you at all, I recommend you create a worker goroutines to process only directories, links: https://blog.golang.org/pipelines , https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may do concurrent processing by modifying your `visit()` function to not go into subfolders, but launch a new goroutine for each subfolder.

In order to do that, return the special `filepath.SkipDir` error from your `visit()` function if the entry is a directory. Don't forget to check if the `path` inside `visit()` is the subfolder the goroutine is ought to process, because that is also passed to `visit()`, and without this check you would launch goroutines endlessly for the initial folder.

Also you will need some kind of "counter" of how many goroutines are still working in the background, for that you may use [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

Here's a simple implementation of this:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func walkDir(dir string) {
    defer wg.Done()

    visit := func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if f.IsDir() && path != dir {
            wg.Add(1)
            go walkDir(path)
            return filepath.SkipDir
        }
        if f.Mode().IsRegular() {
            fmt.Printf("Visited: %s File name: %s Size: %d bytes\n",
                path, f.Name(), f.Size())
        }
        return nil
    }

    filepath.Walk(dir, visit)
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    root := "folder/to/walk" //flag.Arg(0)

    wg.Add(1)
    walkDir(root)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

**Some notes:**

Depending on the "distribution" of files among subfolders, this may not fully utilize your CPU / storage, as if for example 99% of all the files are in one subfolder, that goroutine will still take the majority of time.

Also note that `fmt.Printf()` calls are serialized, so that will also slow down the process. I assume this was just an example, and in reality you will do some kind of processing / statistics in-memory. Don't forget to also protect concurrent access to variables accessed from your `visit()` function.

Don't worry about the high number of subfolders. It is normal and the Go runtime is capable of handling even hundreds of thousands of goroutines.

Also note that most likely the performance bottleneck will be your storage / hard disk speed, so you may not gain the performance you wish. After a certain point (your hard disk limit), you won't be able to improve performance.

Also launching a new goroutine for each subfolder may not be optimal, it may be that you get better performance by limiting the number of goroutines walking your folders. For that, check out and use a worker pool:

[Is this an idiomatic worker thread pool in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170852/is-this-an-idiomatic-worker-thread-pool-in-go/38172204#38172204)

Comment: I don't master well producer-consumer pattern.  `producer()` send subfolders to walking & `consumer()` print it in mycase. Number of goroutines walking folders is limited with the number of `consumer`.

Comment: @LeMoussel Yes, something like that. In my example instead of launching a new goroutine with `go`, you would just send the `path` on a channel "monitored" by consumers to take out paths to "walk" (by executing `walkDir()`).

Comment: Is there some benchmarking that shows improvement ?

Answer (score 0):

My version of solving this problem

```
func ConcurrentDirWalker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, dir string, paths chan<- string) {
    walker := func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if info.IsDir() && path != dir {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                ConcurrentDirWalker(wg, path, paths)
            }()
            return filepath.SkipDir
        }
        if info.Mode().IsRegular(){
            paths <- path
        }
        return nil
    }
    filepath.Walk(dir, walker)
}

collectorCh := make(chan string, 1000)
files := make([]string, 0)

var wgCollector sync.WaitGroup
wgCollector.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wgCollector.Done()
    for path := range collectorCh {
        files = append(files, path)
    }
}()

root := "/users/me/dev/"
var wgWorkers sync.WaitGroup
wgWorkers.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wgWorkers.Done()
    ConcurrentDirWalker(&wgWorkers, root, collectorCh)
}()

wgWorkers.Wait()
close(collectorCh)
wgCollector.Wait()
```

Comment: Is there some benchmarking that shows improvement ?