# go routine not collecting all objects from channel

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I have one `go-routine` to add the objects into channel and then I have 4 `go-routines` to process objects of channel. The processing is nothing but adding objects to an array. But at few times, the objects are missing from final array. So I am assuming that at some point channel stops to collect objects. I have following code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    j := 0
    for {
        if j == 10 {
            break
        }
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        months := []string{"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"}
        hits := make(chan string)
        i := 0
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer close(hits)
            for {
                if i == 25 {
                    wg.Done()
                    return
                }
                for _, month := range months {
                    hits <- month
                }
                i++
            }
        }()

        temp := []string{}
        for updateWorker := 1; updateWorker <= 4; updateWorker++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                for hit := range hits {
                    temp = append(temp, hit)
                }
                wg.Done()
                return
            }()
        }

        wg.Wait()

        log.Printf("length of temp %+v\n", len(temp))
        j++
    }
}
```

I am using `sync` library to synchronise routines. I am looping same process 10 times to test if output is consistent. I am expecting output like this:

```
length of temp 175
```

It is 175 because I am sending 7 month strings 25 times.
But sometimes the output is less than 175, I don't know why. I am bit beginner about go routines. So could anybody please help me here finding the reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `updateWorker` goroutines all collect results from the `hits` channel (so far so good), and they all store the result into the `temp` local variable **unsynchronized**. This is not OK.

Access to all variables from multiple goroutines (where at least one of them is a write) must be synchronized.

If you run it with the race detector enabled, it screams about data races (`go run -race app.go`).

It immediately yields valid results if you decrease the number of `updateWorker` goroutines to 1, because then we eliminate the single data race source of your app:

```
for updateWorker := 1; updateWorker <= 1; updateWorker++ {
    // ...
}
```

If you want to keep multiple `updateWorker` goroutines, their access to the shared `temp` variable must be synchronized.

With a [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex):

```
var (
    mu   sync.Mutex
    temp []string
)
for updateWorker := 1; updateWorker <= 4; updateWorker++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for hit := range hits {
            mu.Lock()
            temp = append(temp, hit)
            mu.Unlock()
        }
        wg.Done()
        return
    }()
}
```

Also note that in this simple example you gain nothing by using multiple `updateWorker` goroutines, adding the above synchronization (locking) even makes it less performant compared to having only one of them.

For properly distributing work and collecting results, check out this answer: [Is this an idiomatic worker thread pool in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170852/is-this-an-idiomatic-worker-thread-pool-in-go/38172204#38172204)