# go routine producer-consumer pattern panics

Tags: go, goroutine

I have implemented goroutine's producer-consumer pattern as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170852/is-this-an-idiomatic-worker-thread-pool-in-go/38172204#38172204). But it panics at some times with error saying: "panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter". I have sample code as below:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "log"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "sync"
)

// Test ...
type Test struct {
    PropA []int
    PropB []int
}

// Clone deep-copies a to b
func Clone(a, b interface{}) {

    buff := new(bytes.Buffer)
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(buff)
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(buff)
    enc.Encode(a)
    dec.Decode(b)
}

func main() {
    test := Test{
        PropA: []int{211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222},
        PropB: []int{111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124},
    }
    var wg, wg2 sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan int, 5)
    results := make(chan Test, 5)

    // start consumers
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(ch <-chan int, results chan<- Test) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for propA := range ch {
                var temp Test
                Clone(&test, &temp)
                temp.PropA = []int{propA}
                results <- temp
            }
        }(ch, results)
    }

    // start producing
    go func(ch chan<- int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for _, propA := range test.PropA {
            ch <- propA
        }
        close(ch)
    }(ch)

    wg2.Add(1)
    go func(results <-chan Test) {
        defer wg2.Done()
        for tt := range results {
            log.Printf("finished propA %+v\n", tt.PropA[0])
        }
    }(results)

    wg.Wait() // Wait all consumers to finish processing jobs

    // All jobs are processed, no more values will be sent on results:
    close(results)

    wg2.Wait()
}
```

When I run above code 4-5 times, it panics at least once. At some time, the error message is "panic: send on closed channel". I don't understand how the channel is being closed before producer finishes to send and why Waitgroup counter reaches negative. Can someone please explain me it?

**EDIT**
The stacktrace for panic is as below: (filename for above code is `mycode.go`)

```
panic: send on closed channel
    panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter

goroutine 21 [running]:
sync.(*WaitGroup).Add(0xc420134020, 0xffffffffffffffff)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:75 +0x134
sync.(*WaitGroup).Done(0xc420134020)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:100 +0x34
panic(0x7622e0, 0x80ffa0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:491 +0x283
main.main.func1(0xc420134020, 0xc420136090, 0xc420148000, 0xc42014a000)
    /home/mycode.go:45 +0x80
created by main.main
    /home/mycode.go:39 +0x21d
exit status 2
```

Comment: There's a `defer wg.Done()` in the producer goroutine. However I don't see a corresponding `wg.Add` for it.

Comment: At what line does in panic?

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky I added the stacktrace for panic case

Comment: Not really helpful as this isn't the full code. Line 75/100 does not exist.

Comment: @C4u 75 and 100 are for `waitgroup.go` which is golang source...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bookkeeping on `wg` is off by one because your producer calls `wg.Done()` but there is no `Add()` called to account for it.  The panic has to do with the variability of the go scheduler, but once you see the fix I am sure you will see how you could get a "negative WaitGroup counter" and / or a "send on closed channel" all depending on timing.

The fix is easy, just add a `wg.Add()` before you start your producer.

```
...

wg.Add(1)
// start producing
go func(ch chan<- int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for _, propA := range test.PropA {
        ch <- propA
    }
    close(ch)
}(ch)

...
```

In the future, when you see a "negative WaitGroup counter" it is a guarantee that you aren't matching 1:1 the number of `Add` to `Done`.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you have two points of wg.Done() that maybe can be the problem.
I refactored your code to put just one point of wg.Done() and I removed the wg.Add(1) from the loop that you put it.
Code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/HdwNFrd-u-)

Comment: it will lose the purpose of asynchronous parallel computing. It will just do computing synchronously which is similar as not having goroutine. I had `for loop` in consumer to distribute jobs to different workers for parallel computing.

Comment: I've edited the code to put the goroutine in parallel computing way just like you said.