# Concurrency Problems using unbuffered channel

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I created a tool in Go that could bruteforce subdomains using Go concurrency. The problem is that it just shows first few results. I mean if the threads i specify are 10, it shows 10, if 100 then it shows 100. Any solutions for this. I am following [this](http://divan.github.io/posts/go_concurrency_visualize/) example.

```
func CheckWildcardSubdomain(state *State, domain string, words <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    for {
        preparedSubdomain := <-words + "." + domain
        ipAddress, err := net.LookupHost(preparedSubdomain)

        if err == nil {
            if !state.WildcardIPs.ContainsAny(ipAddress) {
                if state.Verbose == true {
                    fmt.Printf("\n%s", preparedSubdomain)
                }

                state.FinalResults = append(state.FinalResults, preparedSubdomain)
            }
        }
    }
}

func RemoveWildcardSubdomains(state *State, subdomains []string) []string {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var channel = make(chan string)

    wg.Add(state.Threads)

    for i := 0; i < state.Threads; i++ {
        go CheckWildcardSubdomain(state, state.Domain, channel, &wg)
    }

    for _, entry := range subdomains {
        sub := strings.Join(strings.Split(entry, ".")[:2][:], ".")
        channel <- sub
    }

    close(channel)
    wg.Wait()

    return state.FinalResults
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 mistakes that immediately stand out.

First, in `CheckWildcardSubdomain()` you should range over the `words` channel like this:

```
for word := range words {
    preparedSubdomain := word + "." + domain
    // ...
}
```

The `for ... range` over a channel will terminate once all values sent on the channel (sent before the channel was closed) are received. Note that the simple [receive operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) will not terminate nor panic if the channel is closed, instead it will yield the zero value of the channel's element type. So your original loop would never terminate. [Spec: Receive operator:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)

> A receive operation on a [closed](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close) channel can always proceed immediately, yielding the element type's [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) after any previously sent values have been received.

Second, inside `CheckWildcardSubdomain()` the `state.FinalResults` field is read / modified concurrently, without synchronization. This is undefined behavior.

You must synchronize access to this field, e.g. using a mutex, or you should find other ways to communicate and collect results, e.g. using a channel.

See this related question for an elegant, efficient and scalabe way to do it:

[Is this an idiomatic worker thread pool in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170852/is-this-an-idiomatic-worker-thread-pool-in-go/38172204#38172204)